# How To Crop An Image Following Its Outline Border With Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I basically have thousands of images of characters with black outlines, all of these images either have a white background or  some graphic background, usually just a wood texture behind.

What I want is to create a function (opencv/pil/whatever) that will allow me to just autocrop these images, basically remove everything outside the character's outline.

[image: Here's an example]

On The left is the original, uncropped image, on the right is the cropped image. Is this even possible?

Comment: Constant background color is doable if there is contrast between the foreground and background color. But arbitrary textured background is very hard. You would need an AI/Deep Learning approach. See http://remove.bg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple methods you can get most of the way there. Assuming that the background doesn't have any black in it, we can look for the outlined character by just masking on the black color.

[image]

Then we want to fill in everything inside the outline

[image]

And finally we can just white-out everything outside of the mask

[image]

The obvious issue with this particular picture is that we end up catching the enclosed background in Mr. Bean's arm. I don't see a simple way of fixing that. We could try some color histogram matching on the area inside the mask; try to look for areas inside the mask with the same color profile as the area outside the mask, but this will be much more complicated than the currently presented code.

If the current method will work for most of your images and you can easily hand-edit the rest, please do. If it's really not acceptable as an answer, then let me know and I'll make an attempt to solve it if I have the time.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("outlined.png");

# mask for black
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 0, 50);

# find contours (this is using OpenCV 3, if you're using OpenCV 2 or 4, then it returns as [contours, _])
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

# reset and fill mask
mask[:] = 0;
for con in contours:
    mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [con], -1, 255, -1);

# redraw image using mask
img[mask != 255] = (255,255,255);

# show
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```